# Delete New factor levels not present in the training data

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, categorical-data, r-factor

I'm debugging a code with Random Forest package, with barely no previous R experience.

I've reached a point where, excecuting `predict.randomForest`, I get the error:

> New factor levels not present in the training data.

Searching this site I've found the reason and understood that I need to delete the records that are causing the problem.

**How can I isolate (find out) which columns/rows are causing the problems?**

Comment: Start by checking which columns in the matrix of predictors are factors. You can run `str(X)`, where `X` is the matrix of predictors in your training data. Then do the same in your test data, and look in the output to see which one(s) have different numbers or sets of levels.

Comment: Thanks! The RF object has a lot of things on it... which one is the matrix of predictors you are referring to? And how do I check if each column is a factor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you have train.data, which you used to build your model, test.data, which you now want to get predictions for, and your factor variable factor.var1, then you could do:

```
levels(test.data$factor.var1) %in% levels(train.data$factor.var1)
```

Which will produce a logical vector corresponding to the factor levels in test.data, with the "FALSE" entries being the factor levels that were not present in your train.data.

Comment: And if you want to do that for a bunch of variables at once, you could use `lapply(c([names of variables that are factors in quotes separated by commas]), levels(test.data[,x]) %in% levels(train.data[,x])`

Comment: Tanks both!!! I already have the levels on each factor for prediction variable. But as for the one from the training... its inside a complex RandomForest object... how do I know how to get to the actual data?

Comment: If you don't have access to the training data, I'm not sure how you would get that info - the R [randomForest documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) can show you what is returned with the RF object, and I don't see anything that would be helpful in getting the levels. I'd suggest getting the training data if you can.

Comment: I have the input to the training... but it may have some prior processing (I dont know because I didn't make it). So I thought I'd check against the training OUTPUT. This output is the .RData file which contains this object. Doesn't this object contain these levels somewhere?
I mean: how else would the "process.randomforest" method know there are levels not present in the training?
 Thnx!